# Database structure, product prices last 30 days

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

So, I would like to make a database. This database will contain categories (TV, laptop, phone, ...), products (Philips 32PHK4509 black, Panasonic TX-55AX900, ...) and prices of these products per webshop the last 30 days.

I'm wondering how to structure my database. I'm using mySQL atm.

This is what I got so far. But I'm here to ask if this is the most efficient way. Maybe you guys have some ideas

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) where you can learn about basic setup of database structure for requirements like you have.

**Edit:**

Your product/shop table could be with `id, webshop_id, product_id`.
After that add a ShopProductPrice table with `id, shop_product_id, day, price`.
this way you can add even more days if needed without having to change the table structure.

you wouldnt even need the ShopProductPrice ID, since you can use the shop_product_id and day as primary key.

Comment: Some will say that this isn't really an answer, but I think it is.

Comment: @strawberry: You mean because its poorly formatted, or why? (btw. is there any way to get in touch with other users to ask questions in private? :)

Comment: 1. Because it's not much more than a 'link-only' answer - but I think that's more the fault of the question (too broad) than the answer per se. 2. I think that there is, but I always continue the discussion in the comments until the little blue message appears.

Comment: well, i added a short explanation after PHPeters change to the question, so i guess its not only a link only answer anymore... but thanks for the hint.